# Angular : Destroy a service variable on logout

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am working on an angular project in which I have a service(reports.service.ts) which is added as a provider in `app.module.ts`.

Later this service was used in many components and these components modifies variables in that service when a user performs operations.

Later I wanted to reset these service variables to null when the user logs out (and want to reflect this across the entire application/other components).

This is what I did:

```
logout() {
    delete localStorage[AppConfig.USER_INFO_KEY];
    delete localStorage['CURRENT_BOT'];
    delete localStorage['DATE_OBJ'];
    this.Service.savedData = {};
    this.Service.dateObj = {};
    this.Service.token = '';
    this.Service.deleteMsg = '';
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

The problem is when I reset these variables like the way I did, this only resets variable inside the module in which this `logout()` function resides.

P.S. I didn't provide the `reports.service.ts` in other components individually, just added it in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Firstly you should create method inside the service - more elegant way to clear all these things up. Here you do have more about making singleton services which is thing you want to get done. https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're trying to do here - if you aren't importing the service in your other components, how are you accessing the values at all?  Might help to include some more of your code.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery my apologies, I meant I've not listed the service as provider in the components individually.

Comment: @SiddAjmera that seems to be the case! Anyway, can you please tell what do I do in that case?

Answer (score 3):

Strange. Ideally, if the Service is provided in the Root Module, all the places where it is injected as a dependency share the same instance of the service. So if anything changes on the service, it should ideally get reflected in all those components.

Unless you have this service in the `SharedModule` and then you also have lazy-loaded feature modules. In that case each Lazy Loaded module will receive a different instance of this service.

That's why, Angular [condemns providing Services in the Shared Module](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-10):

> Why? A lazy loaded feature module that imports that shared module will make its own copy of the service and likely have undesirable results.

**FIX:**

[Angular Style Guide recommends](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-11) for all the services that have state data to be provided in a `CoreModule`. The `CoreModule` should then be injected into the `AppModule`.

> Do put a singleton service whose instance will be shared throughout the application in the CoreModule (e.g. ExceptionService and LoggerService).

Also, you should **ONLY IMPORT `CoreModule` in the `AppModule`**

That way there would only be a single instance of these services everywhere in your App(unless of course, you're providing a Service in a Component.)

So you should consider creating a `CoreModule` if you haven't already and start moving all these services, for which you need a single application-wide instance into the `CoreModule`.

Also, consider implementing an [**import guard**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-12) so that it throws an error if you try to import the `CoreModule` in any module other than the `AppModule`

Comment: ```@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [SidebarService],

})
export class CoreModule { }```

this is the new core module, the service is only provided there, nowhere else and this module is injected only inside app module, still no luck :(

Comment: There might be a deeper rooted problem in that case. Can you please create a [minimal StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue if possible?

Comment: I'll try, its a rather complex app and I started working on someone else's code, so I need some time to get my head around it too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

In order to delete/remove a local storage item, the correct method is `removeItem(key)`.
Your code should look like this.

```
logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem(AppConfig.USER_INFO_KEY);
    localStorage.removeItem(CURRENT_BOT);
    localStorage.removeItem(DATE_OBJ);
    this.Service.savedData = {};
    this.Service.dateObj = {};
    this.Service.token = '';
    this.Service.deleteMsg = '';
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

If you are using `angular 6+`, your service (`reports.service.ts`) file should have

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

To inject the `ReportService`, you must add a private `reportService` parameter of type ReportService to the constructor as follows.

```
constructor(private reportService: ReportService) { }
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but other variables behaving the same.